# Starting a call from MacBook - Your iPhone needs to use the same iCloud and Facetime

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, continuity

I'm trying to start a call on iPhone 11 using MacBook Pro on macOS Catalina, however I'm getting an error message that says "Your iPhone needs to use the same iCloud and Facetime".

I've double-checked that FaceTime and iCloud accounts are the same on iPhone, yet the message won't go away. Is there a way to know what macOS thinks the accounts on iPhone and macOS are and how they are different? Or is there any other fix for this?

Comment: I have this question too, but it seems no solution is out yet. Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

To see devices attached to an account:

- Sign into the [Apple iCloud](https://icloud.com) via a browser as the account you want to check
- Drop down the arrow next to your name (top right)
- Choose 'Settings'

The screen will then show you devices that are attached to that account.

The device *MUST* be running iOS 8, macOS Yosemite, or watchOS 1 or above (not an issue in your case).

Comment: Does not work, answer does not help

Comment: @Saif what does not work? Don’t your devices run the correct systems?

Comment: Both iPhone and Mac are signed into same apple id, but calling from Mac does not work. (FYI calls from iPhone can be received on Mac but vice-versa does not work.) @SolarMike

Comment: @saif So post your own new question linking to this one.